# Add Option if Not Exists

Tags: codex, options

I need to see if an option, and if does, get the value. If not, I need to add it.

The [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) provides:

```
<?php
$option_name = 'myhack_extraction_length' ;
$new_value = '255' ;

if ( get_option( $option_name ) != $new_value ) {
    update_option( $option_name, $new_value );
} else {
    $deprecated = ' ';
    $autoload = 'no';
    add_option( $option_name, $new_value, $deprecated, $autoload );
}
```

Which supposedly **updates the option name myhack_extraction_length with the value 255. If the option does not exist then use add_option and set autoload to no.**

However, it seems to me that the second half could be called in two ways, if the option does not exist OR if the new value==the option

Is this correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The logic on the IF THEN ELSE does seem a bit wonky. If I'm reading it correctly...

The call to get_option( $option_name ) will return FALSE if the option does not exist or if it has no value.

So the *IF* would be executed:

1. when the option doesn't exist and $new_value != FALSE
2. the option has no value and $new_value != FALSE
3. the option exists and has a value that is != $new value

The update_option() call would then update the value or create the option with $new_value.

The *ELSE* would be called if:

1. the option exists and has the same value as $new_value
2. the option does not exist and the $new_value == FALSE

Answer (score 17):

I don't recommend to use `if (!(get_option("XXXX"))` approach `to check for existence`, as it fails with `false/null/0/empty` legitimate value.

I suggest:

```
if (!option_exists("XXXX")) {
     add_option("XXXX", "valueee");
}
```

code:

```
public function option_exists($name, $site_wide=false){
    global $wpdb; return $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM ". ($site_wide ? $wpdb->base_prefix : $wpdb->prefix). "options WHERE option_name ='$name' LIMIT 1");
}
```

(I had also  submitted this feature as [CORE request](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51699))

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: When using `update_option` : "If the option does not exist, then the option will be added with the option value, with an $autoload value of ‘yes’." - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/

Comment: As I've just commented on the trac there are caches you should use for this too, and you should definitely update the caches after making the database query.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the best approach to this issue is to create IF-ELSE logic like this one:

```
   if(get_option('some_option')){
         update_option('some_option', 'value_we_want_to_add');
    }
    else {
      add_option('some_option', 'value_we_want_to_add');
    }
```

**Logic:** get_option() will return TRUE if that option does exist. In this case we can simply update that option with some value we want to add. This is done by `update_option('some_option','value_we_want_to_add')`. On the other hand, if some_option doesn't exist, get_option will return FALSE and activate ELSE block. Inside else block we gave instruction to create this "some_option" and assign value we want to it.

Optionally, this logic can be changed to match more advanced requirements.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this correct?

If you mean "when does the 'if' execute and when does the 'else' execute, then "No". Look at the condition: `if ( get_option( $option_name ) != $new_value ) {`

If the option does not exist-- `false != '255'` is `true`-- then the first part executes. It also executes if the option exists and the values don't match --`'123' != '255'` is `true`.

The `else` executes only if the values **do** match-- `'255' != '255'` is false, so the `else` part runs. They could match on anything, numbers, strings, booleans-- aka true or false

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a bit with these kind of options management and did it with a different approach...

```
// create or update the token in DB

    switch ( get_option( 'ngitc_token' ) ) {
        case false: 
            echo "<p>Added token to DB</p>";
            delete_option( 'ngitc_token' ); //get_option() will send false if option doesn't exist OR if it's empty. So I take no chances, I delete it before adding it.
            add_option( 'ngitc_token', $token->token );
            break;
        case $token->token:
            echo "<p>No change to DB</p>";
            break; 
        case true:
            echo "<p>Updated token to DB</p>";
            update_option( 'ngitc_token', $token->token );  
            break;   

    }
```

@Steve is answering you perfectly, I'm just adding a possibility on how to approach options managing.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

1. Function checking if $arg / string / exist in mySQL.
2. $arg must be a string / the name of your option /
3. If the function returns true -> option exist; returns false -> there is no option with this name.

/**
*   Check If Option Exist;
*   @param String
*   @return boolean;
*/

```
function exist_option( $arg ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $db_options = $prefix.'options';
    $sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $db_options . ' WHERE option_name LIKE "' . $arg . '"';

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql_query, OBJECT );

    if ( count( $results ) === 0 ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var_dump( exist_option( 'your_option' ) );
```

Result:

true / false

Example: ( create option if not exist ):

```
if( exist_option( 'your_option' ) == false ) {
    add_option( 'your_option', '255', '', true );
}
```

And your answer may be is:

```
$new_value = '255';

if( exist_option( 'myhack_extraction_length' ) == false ) {
    add_option( 'myhack_extraction_length', '255', '', true );
} else {
    if ( get_option( 'myhack_extraction_length' ) == $new_value ) {
        // Your Code Here: or
        return;
    } else {
        update_option( 'myhack_extraction_length', $new_value );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not just dump code, but explain what you are doing and what it is good for - thanks.

Comment: downvoted as there is no reason at all to directly query the DB. In any case `update_option` will add the option if it do not exist so the whole code is pointless.